# Mongoose adding incorrect value in UpdateOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a User's discord ID based on their key to link the two. Here is my code:

```
console.log(user.discordID);
User.updateOne({key: user.key},{discordID: user.discordID}, (err, result) => {
       if(err){
              console.log(err);
              return err;
              }
       console.log("Updated missing User discord ID");
       console.log(result);
       console.log(user.discordID);
});
```

I pass in the user object to the function and have verified the values are correct. The console.logs show the correct value, 660955020694650891, both before and after the update. But in the DB itself after the update the value is 660955020694650900. For the life of me I can't figure out why this is happening and it is derailing other functionality. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably because the number of the discordID is bigger then the 'Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER', which means that javascript can not represent the exact number.
See more information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

You can solve the problem by using BigInt.
See details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt