# (discord.js v14) MongoDB is not saving users discord ids correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I save users' data by their discord IDs to my database and until today I only used it to fetch their data but I tried to fetch users by their ID saved to the database and saw it cannot find the user because the ID in the database is incorrect.

For example, if users id `358262932791885824` it saves it like this `358262932791885800` or if users id `243422653547937792` it saves it like this `243422653547937800`. I was searching for a solution and found out [someone in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657508/mongoose-adding-incorrect-value-in-updateone) saying it's because of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` but I didn't understand it and couldn't find a solution for the problem. Would be very happy if you help me understand the situation and solve the problem!

**If the user doesn't have data saved on his discord ID this code creates a new one**

```js
        let kontrol = await user.findOne({discord_id: message.author.id});
        if (!kontrol) {
            let newUser = new user({
                discord_id: message.author.id,
                xp: 0,
                level: 0,
                money: 0,
                inventory: [],
                daily: {
                    last: 0,
                    next: 0
                },
                warnings: {
                    adWarn: 0
                }
            })
            await newUser.save();
        }
```

**My user schema**

````js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    discord_id: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    xp: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },

    level: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },

    money: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },

    inventory: {
        type: Array,
        default: [],
        required: true
    },

    daily: {
        last: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
            required: true
        },
        next: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
            required: true
        }
    },

    warnings: {
        adWarn: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
            required: true
        },
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user)
```js


Tried to save users datas with discord ids.
Data saved without error or problem but the discord id is not correct.
When i try to fetch data by id tho, theres no problem fetching it from database.
But when i try to fetch user by id from database, i cant.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means `discord_id` should be a string. Every Discord ID/snowflake should be stored as a string. If you store an ID as an integer and it's larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2^53) it will not be representable in the number type and will be converted to something else by JavaScript (like changing the last to digits to zeroes).

```js
discord_id: {
  type: String,
  // ...
}
```

Also see [Why is my query output showing something completely different than what it is in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68639999/6126373) and [Modified data when using sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72785868/6126373)

Comment: I tried making it String last night and it didnt solve my problem but I was sleepy and not sure about it so Im gonna retry asap and comment u again.

Comment: It won't convert the current IDs to the correct ones. If you change the schema, the current IDs will still be incorrect but the new ones will work as expected.

Comment: I know it wont change exiting ones. I tried to create new data after making it String and as I remember it was still incorrect but gonna try it again asap no worries.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked as expected, sorry its my bad. Thx for the assist!